# .htaccess help to RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem, surprise ;)

I use .htaccess in Apache and have a RewriteRule problem

My code is

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$       /system/header_codes.php?oldurl=$1
```

How can I make if it did not have a true ( rewriterule ) so use this, I will use it becures i create a dyanmic RewriteRule for my customer in my System?

i hope for help here, sorry for bad spelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be way off here becuase I barely get what you're asking, but maybe this will help a little. It's the rewrite rule I use to send everything to my request handler (index.php). It doesn't redirect css, image, etc files, so maybe you can use that logic to exclude other patterns.

```
RewriteRule !(\.(css|jpg|png|gif|jpeg|js|swf))$ index.php [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little hard to understand, but if I'm not mistaken, you want to redirect the user to a custom page IF the rewrite rule is not matched.

Now I will explain the problem with that:

The rewrite rule is designed to *intercept* requests to certain URLs and redirect them to another page. If the rule is not matched, *nothing happens* and the request is handled normally by the webserver.

What you can do, is set a rule in your .htaccess file to redirect requests to nonexistent pages to another file. (See [here](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/custom404error.html))